# Recurrence of events (LINQ query)

Tags: c#, linq

I have `DateStart`, `DateEnd` `Periodicity`, `TypePeriodicity` fields.

We have a query:

```
var result = Events.Where(e => e.DateStart <=today && e.DateEnd >= today).ToList();
```

I want that this query to check `Periodicity`.

For example:

```
name  - record1
DateStart = 2012-02-02
DateEnd = 2012-03-31
Periodicity = 2
TypePeriodicity = 1 ( it's mean a week, may be also day = 0, month=2):
```

I want the following, if current date equals:

```
2,3,4,5 February - return `record1`   
6,7,8..12 - not return, because TypePeriodicity = 1 and Periodicity = 2, which means every 2 weeks
13..19 - return `record1`
20..26 - not return  
and so on until `DateEnd`
```

Thanks.

PS. Maybe not LINQ, but simple method that recieve `result` as parameter.

Comment: Hmm.. It's not very clear from your example what you are trying to achieve, maybe you can expand on your example a bit?

Comment: If `DateStart` is Feb 21st, why is there a match for `2,3,4,5 Feb`?

Comment: I want to... Go ahead. What's the question?

Comment: I want a query or method that parse 'result' that return 'record1'  as show in example.Now, my query will return 'record1' in range from 2 February to 31 March.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something to get you started:

You could define a DateEvaluator delegate like so:

```
    delegate bool DateEvaluator(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, DateTime dateToCheck, int periodicity);
```

The purpose of the delegate would be to evaluate for a given periodicity type if a date should be considered as within range. We would have hence 3 date evaluators. 
One for each period type: Lets call them `dayPeriodicityChecker`, `weekPeriodicityChecker` and `monthPeriodicityChecker`

Our `dayPeriodicityChecker` is straightforward:

```
        DateEvaluator dayPeriodicityChecker = (startDate, endDate, dateToCheck, periodicity) =>
            {
                if ((dateToCheck < startDate) || (dateToCheck > endDate))
                    return false;

                TimeSpan dateDiff = dateToCheck - startDate;
                return dateDiff.Days % periodicity == 0;
            };
```

Our `weekPeriodicityChecker` needs to account for the start day of week, so the start date would need to be adjusted to the date in which the startDate week actually starts:

```
        DateEvaluator weekPeriodicityChecker = (startDate, endDate, dateToCheck, periodicity) =>
            {
                if ((dateToCheck < startDate) || (dateToCheck > endDate))
                    return false;

                DateTime adjustedStartDate = startDate.AddDays(-(int)startDate.DayOfWeek + 1);
                TimeSpan dateDiff = dateToCheck - adjustedStartDate;
                return (dateDiff.Days / 7) % periodicity == 0;
            };
```

Our `monthPeriodicityChecker` needs to cater for months with a variable number of days:

```
        DateEvaluator monthPeriodicityChecker dateToCheck, periodicity) =>
            {
                if ((dateToCheck < startDate) || (dateToCheck > endDate))
                    return false;

                int monthDiff = 0; 
                while (startDate.AddMonths(1) < dateToCheck)
                {
                    monthDiff++
                    // i'm sure there is a speedier way to calculate the month difference, but this should do for the purpose of this example 
                }

                return (monthDiff - 1) % periodicity == 0;
            };
```

Once you have all your date evaluators defined you could put them in an array like so:

```
        DateEvaluator[] dateEvaluators = new DateEvaluator[] 
        {
            dayPeriodicityChecker,
            weekPeriodicityChecker,
            monthPeriodicityChecker
        };
```

This will allow you to do :

```
int periodicityType = 0; // or 1=week or 2=months
bool isDateIn = dateEvaluators[periodicityType ](startDate, endDate, dateTocheck, Periodicity)
```

So lets test this:

```
        PeriodicityEvent pEvent = new PeriodicityEvent
        {
            Name = "record1",
            DateStart = new DateTime(2012, 02, 02),
            DateEnd = new DateTime(2012, 03, 31),
            PeriodicityType = 1,
            Periodicity = 2
        };

        DateTime baseDate = new DateTime(2012, 02, 01);
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
            DateTime testDate = baseDate.AddDays(i);
            if (dateEvaluators[pEvent.PeriodicityType](pEvent.DateStart, pEvent.DateEnd, testDate, pEvent.Periodicity))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is in", testDate.ToString("dd MMM"));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is out", testDate.ToString("dd MMM"));
            }
   }
```

This will produce the desired output as below:

[image: Week evaluation output]

To use you would simply do:

```
Events.Where(e => dateEvaluators[e.PeriodType](e.DateStart, e.DateEnd, today, e.Periodicity).ToList();
```

Good luck!

Comment: monthPeriodicityChecker always skip first month.

Comment: Yup, actually it skipped quite a few of them :) - I've updated the sample, its more of a demonstration of an approach, but it should work now.